# how do i implement brush.move in d3 v3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, brush

I am trying to replicate the brush behavior as in this example:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/87746f16b83cb9d5371394a001cbd772

My main focus is to make brush select entire x-range onclick. The above example does exactly the same but is implemented in d3v4. In d3v3, brush.move and .map() functions are not available. I am trying to d3v3 equivalent of brush.move. Currently my code looks like this:

```
//brush slider display
                context.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "brush")
                    .call(brush)
                    .call(brush.event)
                    .selectAll("rect")
                    .attr("y", -6)
                    .attr("height", brushHeight + 7);

                context.append("g")
                    .call(brush)
                    .call(brush.event)
                    .selectAll(".overlay")
                    .on("mousedown touchstart", beforebrushed, true);

                /**
                 * beforeBrushed function
                 */
                function beforebrushed () {
                    logger.info("beforebrushed activated");
                    d3.event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    d3.select(".brush").transition().call(brush.move, x.range());
                }
```

beforebrushed function is not even called. Instead this error is being thrown on the line where I am using brush.move.
 **TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined**

Any suggestion would be of great help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `brush.move` in d3v3, you should use `brush.event` for this

```
...
.call(brush)
.call(brush.event);
...
```

I rewrote `blocks` which you mentioned with d3v3. Check, please. A lot of code had to rewrite. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

```js
var randomX = function() { return Math.random() * 10 },
    randomY = d3.random.normal(0.5, 0.12),
    data = d3.range(800).map(function() { return [randomX(), randomY()]; });

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 214, left: 10},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, width])
    .domain([0, 10]);
    
var defaultExtent = [3, 5];

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
 .x(x)
  .extent(defaultExtent)
 .on("brush", brushed)

var dot = g.append("g")
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.2)
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d[0]) + "," + y(d[1]) + ")"; })
    .attr("r", 3.5);

var brushContainer = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.event);
    
brushContainer.selectAll("rect")
  .attr("height", height);
 
brushContainer.selectAll(".background")
  .on("mousedown", beforebrushed, true)
  .on("touchstart", beforebrushed, true);

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x));

function brushed() {
  var extent = brush.extent();

  dot.classed("selected", function(d) { return extent[0] <= d[0] && d[0] <= extent[1]; });
}

function beforebrushed() {
  d3.event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  
  brushContainer.transition()
    .duration(700)
     .call(brush.extent([0, 10]))
      .call(brush.event);
}
```

```css
.selected {
  fill: red;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke: brown;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.5/d3.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="306"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! yes the solution you provided works correctly. Though for me it is working only once and then brush control stops working. So trying to fix that. But thank you for providing the solution :)

Comment: can you please explain the significance of this code:
g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x));

Comment: @user2128 This code adds a horizontal axis with ticks from `0` to `10` at the bottom of the chart. `g.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")` here we add `g` element and move it to the height of chart. `.attr("class", "axis")` here - add `class` attribute, we apply some styles on this class name. With this code -
 `.call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x))`, d3 generate appropriate svg elements for displaying axis and ticks.

Comment: I dont see that issue in cope snippet you have given. But brushContainer.transition()
    .duration(700)
     .call(brush.extent([0, 10]))
      .call(brush.event); -- this code expands the brush extent to entire x range and then disables the brush controls for me. Did you face the same issue while implementing the code?

Comment: No, I had no faced with this problem. Check if after expanding the `rect` with class name `background` and `rect` with class name `extend` have the same values of attributes `x` and `width`. https://www.evernote.com/l/As3CwDwTAilCl5ajXZXDVo_TsPYV5aml6TUB/image.png

Comment: Yes width of extent and background is same!